# java jpa commit-ит сам по себе

Tags: java, jpa

Использую `jpa`. Достаю из базы `entity` объект. У него в поле `body => blob` там хранится `xml` файл. После того как распарсил `xml` что бы освободить память делаю `wm.setBody(null);` после этого он сам по себе удаляет содержимое поля `body`. 
Как сделать что бы он не очищал поле?

Comment: Вызывать `wm.setBody(null);` не в транзакционном методе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не делай так: `wm.setBody(null)`. Если это происходит в транзакции, то он (jpa) следит за изменениями и при завершении записывает их в базу.
Как советуют в комментарии `wm.setBody(null)` вызывать вне транзакции.
Иначе можно отключить entity от контекста, сделать его detached: `em.detach(wm)`. Тогда jpa забудет про него даже в транзакции.
Если поле lazy или нужно только это поле из всего entity, то можно загружать только его отдельным запросом. Будет простая переменная типа String (или чего там у Вас для xml), которую уж как-нибудь освободите. `String body = em.createQuery("SELECT wm.body FROM ...`

И ещё на всякий случай напомню, что этот объект со своим body может храниться в кеше второго уровня. Так что очистка будет только на половину.

Comment: А если мне нужно в дальнейшем использовать wm? У него только body больше не используется.

Comment: В дальнейшем можно например получить новую копию этого объекта. Смотря что нужно от этого объекта. Если его изменять не планируется, то можно так detached и использовать. Будут там и id и дата и все ссылки работать. Но при попытке сохранить получите тот же эффект.

Comment: там дата, Ид хранятся. Их в дальнейшем доставать надо. А боди не нужен

Comment: Если body ни для чего больше не нужен, сделайте его lazy и поступайте как в последнем варианте. Правда утверждается, что не все провайдеры jpa поддерживают lazy на простых полях.